# gtsummary , 5 point complex survey design scale and median

Tags: gtsummary

I am trying to use the tbl_svysummary for a likert scale survey ordinal data: "very bad", "bad", "moderate", "good", "very good" and I have five such questions are there.

I need to summaries  the median.

Could not find any example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tbl_likert()` function for this from the bstfun package (which includes gtsummary extensions)
https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/bstfun/reference/tbl_likert.html

```r
set.seed(1123)
likert_lvls <- c("Never", "Sometimes",  "Often", "Always")

df <-
  tibble::tibble(
    Q1 = sample(likert_lvls, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
    Q2 = sample(likert_lvls, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Q1, Q2), ~factor(., levels = likert_lvls)))

tbl_likert_ex1 <-
  tbl_likert(df) %>%
  add_n() %>%
  add_continuous_stat(statistic = "{mean}") %>%
  add_continuous_stat(statistic = "{sd}")
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use the survey design object using survey package and call the tbl_likert function?

Comment: Apologies, I missed the survey detail when I read your original post. `tbl_likert()` and `add_continuous()` a short-ish wrappers that could be rewritten using, for example, `tbl_svysummary()` instead of `tbl_summary()`.

Comment: This is great. Please help by sharing the details . regards